# How can I take list item's value of home menu tab in outlook using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I am trying to take out list item's value of Home Menu Bar using VB.net code but I am not able to do so.
How can I take all the values of Home(Mail) Menu item that is there in the screenshot

Here's my code snippet:

currentExplorer = Globals.Connect.Application.ActiveExplorer()

Dim MenuBar As Office.CommandBarControls

MenuBar = currentExplorer.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls("Home").Controls

**More Information** :

Outlook 365 version : 2019(32bit)

Visual Studio 2019

Windows 10 pro

**I am also attaching a screenshot for for clarification**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRWkj.png)

Answer (score 0):

If it is your control, you can only get the value from a callback when the control changes.